# NSMutableAttributedString how to place 1 big word and then 2 lines after

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring, core-text, nsmutableattributedstring

Please look at this picture:

[image]

Notice how "Strength" is in big font and then "is not" is smaller and "something" is even smaller. I know how I can alter fonts in NSMutableAttributedString. However I don't know how I can put the 1st line "is not something" and "you have, rather" as second line - BOTH sharing the same line as "Strength".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with a single `UILabel`. You will need at least two `UILabel`s, and it would be easiest with three or four (depending on whether you want to use a separate label for the hashtag at the end).